# How to filter a List<T> if it contains specific class data?

Tags: c#, generic-list

I need help with filtering list data in c#.
I got 3 class named `Product.cs`, `Storage.cs` and `Inventory.cs`.

```
public class Storage{
    string StorageId;
    string Name;
}

public class Inventory{
    string InventoryId;
    string StorageId; 
    string ProductId;
}
```

I got the filled `List<Storage> mStorages`, `List<Product> mProduct` and `List<Inventory> mInventories`.

I have trouble to print `mStorages` that contain with specific `productId` that only can be obtained from `mInventories`.

So, I tried this:

```
List<Storage> mFilteredStorage;
for(int i=0;i<mStorages.Count;i++){
    if(mStorages[i] contain (productId from inventories)){
        mFilteredStorage.add(mstorages[i]);
}
```

So I can get `mFilteredStorage` that contains specific product from inventories. (in inventories there are lot of product id).

What should I do to get that `filteredStorage`? I tried to use `list.contains()` but it only return true and at last there are duplicated storage at `mFilteredStorage`.

Really need your help guys. Thanks in advance.

Comment: mFilteredStorage.AddRange(mStorages.where(f=> inventories.any(g=> g.productId==f.productId)).Tolist())

Comment: Is your software backed by a Database? Because this sounds perfectly for something to be performed in SQL , for example.

Comment: I don't see `ProductId` in `Storage`. How will you match that?

Comment: could you clarify , from where you get specific product id ?

Comment: Depending on you model you could reference Storage directly in your Inventory class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to read about [lambda-expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-use-lambda-expressions-in-a-query), that is what you are looking for.

```
mFilteredStorage.AddRange(mStorages.Where(storage => inventories.Any(inventory => inventory.productId == storage.productId)).ToList());
```

This returns you a list with your filtered conditions. So right after `Where` you iterate over each item in your list, I called this item `storage`. (you can name those what ever you want to) Then we iterate over your object `inventories` with another lambda expression. This, the second lambda expression, returns either true if any of `inventories`'s productIds match the productId of the current iterating object of `mStorages` or false if they don't match.

So you once the productIds match you can imagine the code like the following:

```
mStorages.Where(storage => true);
```

And once the result of the second lambda expression is true, `storage` will be added to the `IEnumerable` you will get as a result of the `Where` method.

Since we get an `IEnumerable` as return, but we want to add those `Storage` objects to `mFilteredStorage`, I convert the `IEnumerable` to a list, by:

```
/*(the return object we get from the `Where` method)*/.ToList();
```

Comment: this thing also works for me, but its not easy to learn that lamda.Thanks

Comment: @YeremiaDanang You are welcome. But I understand you, that it is hard to understand that nested lambda. Start with a normla basic lambda at first. Look at the code at first like that: `mStorages.Where(storage => /*some bool value*/);`. Once this bool value is true this `storage` object of `mStorages` will get returned. So "some bool value" can be any condition (returned bool value), e.g. `1 == 0` or just `true` or a condition with the list object like: `storage => storage == ...`. And since your condition is complex I added another lambda at the "...", to filter with another condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to accomplish your goal. Since `Storage` has no `ProductId`, the query will match by `StorageId`.

```
var filteredStoragesQry =
    from storage in mStorages
    where inventories.Any(inventory => inventory.StorageId == storage.StorageId)
    select storage;
mFilteredStorages = filteredStoragesQry.ToList();
```

This query is for LINQ to objects, but it will also work in Entity Framework, when you replace `mStorages` and `inventories` by the respective `DbSet` objects from the context.

Answer (score 0):

```
mStorages.Join(mInventories, x => x.StorageId, y => y.StorageId, (x, y) => new { Storage = x, ProductId = y.ProductId})
            .Where(z => z.ProductId == "specificProductId").Select(z => z.Storage).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended with this code.

```
mFilteredStorage = tempStorage.GroupBy(s => s.Id).Select(group => group.First()).ToList()
```

This code is what I want to show.